# RELACION MUCHOS A MUCHOS LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

estoy tratando de hacer una relación y una consulta pero al parecer algo está mal porque no es lo que estoy buscando. Aún estoy empezando con laravel y aún tengo dudas.

Mis tablas resumidas son las siguientes:
[image: Mis tablas resumidas son las siguientes:]

[image: Y los datos que deseo obtener de las consultas son las siguientes:]
Y los datos que deseo obtener de las consultas son las siguientes:

Si alguien me puede ayudar, sería genial. Gracias.

Comment: mira este tutorial para aprender un poco mas de las relaciones de muchos a muchos https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1068-relacion-muchos-a-muchos-con-laravel-y-eloquent/

Comment: Cuando tienes una tabla N:M se necesita una tabla intermedia o en laravel llamada pivot [(DOCUMENTACIÓN)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) <?php namespace App; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class Producto extends Model { public function marcas() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Marca'); } } PD: todas las tablas necesitan ID para que eloquent trabaje con ellas o modificar los modelos y la clave por defecto de las relaciones